# RxAndroid - Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have the following peace of code containing network operations. Where I get the well known error `Error in http connectionandroid.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` which is pretty descriptive and explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

What I don't understand is, how can the error occur here when I clearly subscribe on `Scheduler.io()`. What do I do wrong?

```
ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(mContext);
locationProvider.getLastKnownLocation().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe((location -> {
    // ... unrelated code
    try {
        this.postPing(pingResponse); // <<< this is an http post causing the error
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "trying to post response");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Edit: This does not seem to be entirely trivial. That's why I provide additional context.

The code above used to look like this and didn't use `ReactiveLocationProvider`, but rather the `FusedLocationApi`

```
 Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient);
                    // ... unrelated code
                    try {
                        this.postPing(pingResponse);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "trying to post response");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cursor.close();
```

And was run from within a GcmListenerService:

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        Log.d("GCMListener", "onMessageReceived");
        String action = data.getString("action");
        switch (action) {
            case "getPing":
                requests.getPingObservable()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).retryWhen(
                        errors ->
                                errors
                                        .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (n, i) -> i)
                                        .flatMap(retryCount -> Observable.timer((long) Math.pow(5, retryCount), TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                        ).subscribe((pingsJsonObjectString) -> {
                }, (error) -> error.printStackTrace());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately the GcmListenerService doesn't receive notifications when the app is closed. So I decided to cheat a bit and create an alarm to trigger the reciever with an alarm.

In The `AndroidMainfest.xml` I added the line `<category android:name="com.smilingkoala.ping.periodic_wakeup"/>`

```
<!-- The Google Cloud Messaging receiver and services -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.smilingkoala.ping" />
                <category android:name="com.smilingkoala.ping.periodic_wakeup"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and in `MainActivity.java` I called:

```
public void startAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.smilingkoala.ping.periodic_wakeup");
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES / 3, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, sender);
}
```

To restart the listener once the application is closed.
This actually worked. I received a message. But now I didn't have access to `MainActivity.mGoogleApiClient` which I used in the old code. That's why I was forced to use `ReactiveLocationProvider`. However now i can't run the networking code.

I assume something I did leading up to this Error is forbidden.

Comment: The subscribe happens back on the UI thread?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly, but If you mean the script around the code snipped above then no. It's part of an observable called also on `Schedulers.io`.

Comment: Well, `this.postPing(pingResponse);`seems to be happening on the main thread, yes? Otherwise, why are you getting an error?

Comment: @cricket_007 So when I call a method from within subscribe it is not run on the same thread, as the rest of the stuff in subscribe?

Comment: Should all be on the same thread. That is just the first method that requires not to be on the main thread. I don't really have any examples of network calls on RxJava

Comment: @cricket_007 "Should all be on the same thread." So you understand how weird this is for me. I don't even know how to tackle debugging this. Any tips on this?

Comment: Try with a simpler example. Is all that location code really necessary to debug the issue?

Comment: @Lukasz is the try/catch code executed in an Observable operator such as map/doOnNext etc? Is it in the final subscribe() call?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos the try catch is in the subscribe of `getLastKnownLocation()`, however this is itself called within the observable `getPingObservable()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I am not 100% sure, but let's try to explain this (:

If you read [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) on `.subscribeOn` operator, you'll see that it defines scheduler on which Observable *itself* (not the Subscriber!) will be executed. You need to explicitly define scheduler for subscriber with `.observeOn` operator, or it will be executed on thread where it was subscribed on.

For more detailed information and examples you should check these links:
http://www.grahamlea.com/2014/07/rxjava-threading-examples/
http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#SubscribeOnObserveOn

Also you can debug and experiment with threading by calling `Thread.currentThread()` to check where is your code executing.

Comment: As you said I mixed up subscribeOn and observeOn. changing those solved it. Thanks.